# Translate string into TIPA

Tags: conversion, strings, tipa

I am writing a project about phonetics using the `tipa` package. The problem is, I need to publish two separate versions of my project using different phonetic notation standards. When considering the fact that there is, fortunately, a one-to-one correlation between the symbols of these two standards, I would like to know if there is a way to convert from the one standard to the other without having to write everything twice?

Furthermore, since I am only using a small selection of the symbols available in `tipa`, I would like to use a custom syntax which eases typing.

What I need to create is a command `phone` in which I can type phonetic writing using my own custom syntax. The `phone` command is then supposed to convert this into the `tipa` syntax. If that is possible, all I have to do to convert between these two standards is to change this command.

An example: Since I'm using `\textraiseglotstop` and `\textsubarch{5}` a lot, I would `phone` to replace `?` with `\textraiseglotstop` and `R` with `\textsubarch{5}`.

If somebody can provide me with a command that enables me to make lots of substring conversions without causing conflicts, I think that would suffice. Other suggestions are also very welcome, though.

Comment: Are the two transcriptions systems ever found in the same document?  Or are they distinct in each version?

Comment: They are going to be distinct. However, if possible, I wouldn't mind having both at my disposal so that I could make a conversion table, but it's not strictly necessary. But maybe the best is to have two commands: `\standard1` and `\standard2`. Then `\phone` can be set to either depending on which version of the document is to be produced. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be to use macros for the variant characters and use a conditional to switch between them.  Here's a simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipa}
\newif\ifregularIPA
\regularIPAtrue
\newcommand*{\GS}{\ifregularIPA\textglotstop\else\textsuperscript{?}\fi}
\begin{document}
\begin{IPA}
\GS aral

\regularIPAfalse
\GS aral
\end{IPA}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

For the different versions of the document you would set the switch once in the preamble.  For making a table of conversions you can set the switch inside a group.

Comment: Thanks :-) ... But is it not possible to create a command `phone` so that `\phone{?aral}` is equivalent to `\textipa{\textraiseglotstop{}aral}`?

Comment: I don't see what you gain from doing that. You need some markup for IPA anyway, so I don't see the difference between `\phone{?aral}` and `\textipa{\GS aral}`. Or is your problem actually a different one, and you have things *already* in some orthographic form and you want to translate them to IPA.  That's a different problem.  But if you're entering the elements directly, this method is really the simplest.

Comment: Well, only the fact that it takes much less time to type when writing a long project ;-). What I want is to let the project rely entirely on my custom syntax, assigning a one-letter code to all the symbols I'm going to use :-). And I'm going to write the project from scratch using this system. ;-)

Comment: While this is *possible*, (involves making characters 'active') it's likely to cause more problems than it's worth.  You can just as easily configure your editor to enter the markup in a single keystroke if you want to save typing time.

Comment: Wouldn't it somehow be possible to make a lot of substring replacements on the same string? In order to avoid conflicts, I would probably have to make two conversions, e.g. `?` --> `code01` --> `\GS`. But would it somehow be possible to make these multiple substitutions? :-)

Comment: I don't want to belabor the point, but I really think this is very much a case of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/170190).